# How to perform GCP authentication from within the Docker image to be run on Cloud Run?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

In a Docker image which runs some scripts and at the end of the script I use the `bq` command to append the data to a BigQuery table. This all works fine offline when I don't run it within Docker since my local dev environmen has the proper authentication set up.

The issue is how do I set up authentication so that I can run `bq` from within docker when I do `docker run -t my-image`.

Also, after I upload it to the gcr.io registry and run it as a job in cloud run. How do I authenticate?

Looking up authentication documentation (e.g. https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/provide-credentials-adc) is a like a maze and googling doesn't turn up very useful results

Comment: Did you try to run your container on Cloud Run jobs? Did you get an error? Did you use a custom service account? Is the Cloud Run Job runtime service account has the permission to access BQ?

Comment: Yeah. Got error about not having bq.create.jobs I figured it out. Will post an answer

Comment: Can you share your solution, so that it helps others as well?

Answer (score 1):

From a recent project a made... (All commands have an equivalent in the GCP Console UI, if you are more familiar with)

**Assumptions:**

1. knowledge of IAM,
2. the docker container running a service impersonating a dedicated IAM service account (SA).

**Create the service account (SA) and deploy the docker image as a Run service --------------**

```
# RUN_SERVICE_NAME the name of your Run service as you deploy it in GCP
# SERVICE_ACCOUNT the name of the dedicated service account the service uses
# SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FRIENDLY_NAME an easy name for you to read
# SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL the email GCP gives you back when you create the SA

gcloud iam service-accounts create $SERVICE_ACCOUNT --display-name "$SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FRIENDLY_NAME"

gcloud run deploy $RUN_SERVICE_NAME \
    --service-account $SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL
    ....
    ....
```

The SA must have roles to access or edit the BQ dataset and table (ref.: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/control-access-to-resources-iam#grant_access_to_a_table_or_view)

You can download BQ config to a json file your dev machine...

**For Dataset -----------------------------------**

```
# BigQuery get the dataset full info
bq show \
   --format=prettyjson \
   $PROJECT:$DATASET_NAME > $DATASET_NAME.json
```

Then update the file to include the BQ roles.. (<SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL> replace with your SA email, <BQ_ROLE_1> and <BQ_ROLE_2> with your roles).:

```
{
  "access": [
    ....
    ....

    {
      "role": "<BQ_ROLE_1>",
      "userByEmail": "<SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL>"
    }
  ],

  ....
  ....
}
```

Finally update the policy:

```
# BigQuery update dataset permissions
bq update --source $DATASET_NAME.json $PROJECT:$DATASET_NAME
```

**For Table --------------------------------**

```
# BigQuery get the policy of a table
bq get-iam-policy \
   $PROJECT:$DATASET_NAME.$DATASET_TABLE_NAME \
   > $DATASET_NAME.$DATASET_TABLE_NAME.json
```

Then update the file to include the BQ roles, eg.:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "members": [
        "<SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL>"
      ],
      "role": "<BQ_ROLE_2>"
    }
  ],
  ....
  ....
}
```

Finally update the policy:

```
bq set-iam-policy $PROJECT:$DATASET_NAME.$DATASET_TABLE_NAME $DATASET_NAME.$DATASET_TABLE_NAME.json
```

In your service code (example made with NodeJS):

```
const { BigQuery } = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');
const bigqueryClient = new BigQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

On the GCP CloudRun it's quite simple, in the settings page for the Job you can select a Service Account to run the image as. As long as that service has the right access to bigquery then it should work.

For offline docker. Still not sure.